# Is it possible to adjust the length of a GeoJSON LineString?

Tags: geojson, linestring

Let's say I have the following GeoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-88.0344009399414, 43.11040115356445]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-89.3375015258789, 43.13990020751953]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "feature_type": "line"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-88.0344009399414, 43.11040115356445],
                    [-89.3375015258789, 43.13990020751953]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above is a line between two points. I want to shorten that line by some x amount so it doesn't go all the way to the points at the beginning and end. Is there a way to do this without changing the start and end points for the line? To say, for example shorten the line by 50px or something like that?

I know you can do this when creating a polyline in leaflet, but can't find any settings on a GeoJSON LineString that would allow me to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, there is no 'length' property in the [definition](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring) of a line string in the geojson spec. You need to use the start and end points.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in your geojson to geojs on.io
And edit it

Comment: That's a very helpful website. The issue is I haven't been able to find any documentation that says how to do this, and can't guess at how I would do it.